# Visual Studio Form Editor: How do I add title text-style mouseover to a button?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have a `System.Windows.Forms.Button` control, and I want to add a hover-text explanation of what the button will do. I were writing a webapp, the answer to my question would be approximately this easy:

```
<input type="button" title="This is the answer" />
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Express. I've checked all the properties I could find for this `Button`, but I don't see anything that does what I want. Google searches turned up 50% confusing, elaborate answers, and the other half were tauntingly easy HTML examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you want to use the [ToolTip Component (Windows Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he23h308.aspx) at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he23h308.aspx

[How to: Set ToolTips for Controls on a Windows Form at Design Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s894w4aa.aspx)
 at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s894w4aa.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Tooltip Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) to achieve the desired effect.

Just initialize the tooltip values you want on the controls you want.

```
...
toolTip1.SetToolTip(button1, "This is the answer");
...
```